Can MDM collect screen time reports from managed devices by using Apple’s framework?
Looking at the docs, the only restriction I found is related to Screen Time settings modification.
Is there any way to see user's screen time thru MDM?

No, that isn’t a public method that Apple provides MDM vendors to consume reports of data from managed devices. Specifically, Apple classifies screen time data as personal data and not work data.

https://www.apple.com/business/docs/resources/Managing_Devices_and_Corporate_Data.pdf

On the consumer side, there are similar documents explaining how Apple never wants to see that data either from any device.

https://support.apple.com/guide/security/screen-time-security-secd8831e732/web

For consumer devices, this is something designed to never send this data off device unless it’s encrypted end to end and only in the case of a parent - child relationship for the Apple ID is pre-established.

Many thanks. I wanted to get screen time from my child's phone. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Yes, @LA_ and you don’t need MDM. First figure it your child”s age allows them to make an Apple Account - https://support.apple.com/en-us/102617 then set them up as a Family member with your account (or another adult) as the organizer. https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/set-up-screen-time-for-a-family-member-ipha200da319/ios

I did it already. The question is how to get this information outside of apple's ecosystem.
